# StringTokenizer with .txt file when no value in the line

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have a programming homework to do and our teacher wants us to use the `StringTokenizer`.
We have a txt file with the `matricule \t name \t first name \t Grade1 \t Grade2 \t Grade3 \t Grade 4` on one line. I want my code to return "0" when the StringTokenizer hit a token with nothing. I am not allowed to use the split function.

here is an example of date :

```
00000005    manque tp1  donne 90        40  100 100
```

Program

```
String line;
        while ((ligne = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer var = new StringTokenizer(ligne, "\t");
            String matricule = var.nextToken();
            String nom = var.nextToken();
            String prenom = var.nextToken();
            double noteTP1 = Double.parseDouble(var.nextToken());
            double noteTP2 = Double.parseDouble(var.nextToken());
            double noteIntra = Double.parseDouble(var.nextToken());
            double noteFinal = Double.parseDouble(var.nextToken());
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `StringTokenizer.countTokens()`

```
        String line;
        while ((ligne = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer var = new StringTokenizer(ligne, "\t");
            if(var.countTokens() == 0) {
                //return "0"; or continue;
            String matricule = var.nextToken();
            String nom = var.nextToken();
            String prenom = var.nextToken();
            double noteTP1 = Double.parseDouble(var.nextToken());
            double noteTP2 = Double.parseDouble(var.nextToken());
            double noteIntra = Double.parseDouble(var.nextToken());
            double noteFinal = Double.parseDouble(var.nextToken());
```

Comment: I tried the return but the file does not go to the next token and the program does not calculate anything. I also tried continue but it doesnt work either. I want the code to replace the null value by a 0 so the program keeps on going.